# Show a from name instead of email address using curl with sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid

I am using curl to send to sendgrid mailer.

I am trying to get it to show my business name in the From instead of the email address.

I have tried this:

```
 'from' => 'Name <example@example.com>'
```

That does not work. Any one got any ideas?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `fromname` parameter. https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html